# UIImagePickerController shows a blank sheet in Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios14, xcode12

I have this very odd situation in Xcode 12.01. In one of the simulators iPhone 11-14.0 when calling UIImagePickerController a blank screen pops-up showing no images and even the Cancel button is not visible. It looks like that the screen is not fully loading.
using the call:

```
 PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
```

I have authorisation to access the photo library as it returns status is `.authorized:`

This is happening for just that particular simulator and the others work as expected. 
Any ideas?
Thanks

[image: call to UIImagePicker Controller]

Answer (score 0):

I finally erase all content and settings from the device menu and it seemed to have resolved the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue. The solution is, upgrade your Xcode to version 12.2, this issue is resolved in Xcode(12.2).

Hop this helps.

Thanks